# Advanrtages of Flex3 over Flex 2

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Can anyone explain the main advantages of Flex3.0 over flex2.0 ? (not advantages of Flex builder).

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex3_whatsnew.html

And here: http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/3/releasenotes_flex3_sdk.html#whatsnew

But depending on the schedule of your project, you might even consider Flex 4.

- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4sdk_whatsnew.html
- http://java.dzone.com/articles/flex4
- http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/whats-new-flex-4
- http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2009-develop/whats-new-in-flex-4/